# Is it possible to use discounts and pay a 3rd party using Paypal mobile SDKs?

Tags: ios, paypal

My app needs the ability to pay different merchants, so essentially I'm acting as a middle man. A user would fill up their cart from one merchant and then I'd present them the whole paypal interface and then that particular merchant would get paid. So first question: is that possible? Or is it only possible for MY account to get paid? If I had 10 merchants, I'd like to directly send them the payment amount (and have them pay the transaction fees).

The other question is discounts. Say a merchant creates a discount of some kind, is it possible with the mobile SDKs to apply these discounts?

My app is for iOS at first but will be quickly followed by an Android and then a web version of it. I don't really care which SDK I use so long as it can meet all my feature needs.

If none of this is possible with any of the SDKs, are there any out there that might accomplish what I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing [chained payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).  You can utilize chained payments by integrating with [classic MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/).  The [new Mobile SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) will support these kinds of payments in the future, so keep on the look out!